# choosing to hide or show tooltips based on bool

Tags: c#, tooltip

so I figured I'm making just a stupid mistake here. In the first of what will be many controls, I need to either show a balloon `tooltip` when a `bool` is true or not show them when the `bool` is false. I know that `ShowAlways` is not what I need to modify and I've tried various solutions already. Does anyone spot the problem? The `bool` is set by a checked dropdown item in a Help Menu Strip Item.

It will open with the application with the correct display, but as soon as I check that option to show it, it always shows there after.

```
public void changeBalloonProperties(bool boolSet)
        {
            ToolTip helpDeskInfoButtonToolTip = new ToolTip();
            if (boolSet)
            {
                helpDeskInfoButtonToolTip.ToolTipTitle = "HelpDesk Information Button";
                helpDeskInfoButtonToolTip.UseFading = true;
                helpDeskInfoButtonToolTip.UseAnimation = true;
                helpDeskInfoButtonToolTip.IsBalloon = true;
                helpDeskInfoButtonToolTip.ShowAlways = true;
                helpDeskInfoButtonToolTip.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
                helpDeskInfoButtonToolTip.InitialDelay = 1000;
                helpDeskInfoButtonToolTip.ReshowDelay = 500;
                helpDeskInfoButtonToolTip.SetToolTip(helpDeskButton, "Click to launch HelpDesk user info page in default browser.");
            }
            else
            {
                helpDeskInfoButtonToolTip.RemoveAll();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new ToolTip instance each time the `changeBalloonProperties` is called so the code isn't removing the caption associated with the original ToolTip that was used with the `helpDeskButton`. Try moving the ToolTip declaration outside of your `changeBalloonProperties` method so the same ToolTip object is used with `RemoveAll()`.

Also note you can use that same ToolTip object to add captions for multiple controls (as shown in the sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip)) and it's probably better to set `helpDeskInfoButtonToolTip.Active = false` to disable them all at once instead of setting and removing the captions (and other properties) each time you toggle.